# Dgrid collection data not accessible after filtering on collection

Tags: dojo, dgrid, dstore

So, I am using `collection` in my `dgrid` and the `store` is of type `[Memory, Trackable]`. I am using store filtering (as given [here](https://github.com/SitePen/dstore/blob/master/docs/Collection.md)). When I filter the store data, then the returned collection object does not have any data attribute and thus I am unable to access the data from the collection. Although, the changes are reflected in the d-grid when I change the collection but I need to access the data from collection to do other things.

Here is my code:

```
var filterObj= new this.store.Filter();
var tagFilter= filterObj.in('tagList', selectedTags);
var newCollection= this.store.filter(tagFilter);
this.grid.set('collection', newCollection);
```

I am unable to retrieve `data` from `newCollection` as well as from `this.grid.collection`. Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `fetch` (and `fetchSync` in the case of `Memory`) APIs are the correct public APIs to use (and that is why dgrid still has no trouble querying the collection).

`data` is an implementation detail, and you shouldn't really be trying to access a store/collection's data via the `data` property.  That is ordinarily present on the root store when it gets mixed in via constructor arguments.